# How did this happen?? Git error? Some other fluke?

Tags: git, sed, ruby-on-rails-3, github

Every file in this Rails project is duplicated with a `-e` and again with a `-e-e` tacked onto the end of it, like the following.  It's that way in my GitHub repository too.  But I can't figure out how it happened.  Any clue?  Google searching comes up empty.

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 usrname  staff   959 Jan  7 02:13 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   958 Jan  5 01:10 Gemfile-e
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   958 Jan  5 01:09 Gemfile-e-e
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff  6650 Jan  7 02:13 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff  6650 Jan  5 01:10 Gemfile.lock-e
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff  6650 Jan  5 01:09 Gemfile.lock-e-e
lrwxr-xr-x   1 usrname  staff    18 Jan  5 00:37 README.rdoc -> doc/README_FOR_APP
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   283 Jan  5 01:10 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   283 Jan  5 01:10 Rakefile-e
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   283 Jan  5 01:09 Rakefile-e-e
drwxr-xr-x   6 usrname  staff   204 Jan  5 00:37 app
drwxr-xr-x   5 usrname  staff   170 Jan  5 01:10 autotest
drwxr-xr-x  28 usrname  staff   952 Jan  5 01:15 config
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   173 Jan  5 01:10 config.ru
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   173 Jan  5 01:10 config.ru-e
-rw-r--r--   1 usrname  staff   173 Jan  5 01:09 config.ru-e-e
```

**The Explanation in Full**

The recursive find and replace command

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/' {} \;
```

works on most linux, but throws an error on mac os x.  The following variant runs, but creates the unwanted '-e' backup files.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/string1/string2/' {} \;
```

This is the actual command that works as expected on mac os x:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "" 's/string1/string2/' {} \;
```

Comment: As you've discovered, OS X `sed` requires an extension for the `-i` option. Using GNU `sed`, the extension is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not do this, nor does Ruby or Rails. There's some script you've ran that has done this. Think back, what did you do before you noticed this?

Comment: Looking through your git history might help do that.

Comment: But I ran sed against the files -- hmmmm  I don't recall sed creating any copies of files .......  If not that, there's really no other possibilities.

Comment: A quick check of 'man sed' shows I must have gotten included a -i in front of a -e, such that it assumed that -e was the suffix to add to the backup when doing 'in place editing' -- mystery solved.

Comment: I've added the actual details of the sed mixup to the bottom of the question.